# Console.Write/Writeline

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i = 4;
            int j = 2;



            Console.Write("numbers " , i , j);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Как правильно написать чтобы отобразилось запись в 1 строчку – числа 4 00?
Смотрю документацию и не понимаю, в методе `Write` получается сначала идёт `String`, а затем `Object`, но если ввести просто `Console.Write(i)` оно всё выведет.

Comment: Читайте внимательней, для чего там String, а для чего Object. Ну и метод с 2 параметрами и метод с 1 параметром - это разные методы

Comment: Прочитал и не совсем всё равно понимаю, я ведь ввёл первый стринговый параметр, дальше object, почему я не могу сколько угодно object добавлять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В методе [`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttxecb1c(v=vs.110).aspx) первый параметр - [формат](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting). То, что вы вводите форматом не является (точнее, является, но он не выведет никакие числа, что вы передаете). Попробуйте задать корректный формат

Допустим, у нас есть 2 переменные

```
int i = 4;
int j = 2;
```

Тогда печать их в консоль будет выглядеть так:

```
Console.Write("numbers {0} {1}", i, j);
```

или воспользуйтесь [интерполяцией строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)

```
Console.Write($"numbers {i} {j}");
```

Comment: Интерполяция строк нужна для подстановки значений переменных по их именам. Показать ее на примере подстановки трех чисел прямо в фигурных скобках - ИМХО так себе идея.

Comment: @insolor интерполяция нужна для подстановки переменных, констант, выражений и проч, а усложнять примеры переменными я не вижу смысла, тем более что в моем ответе имеются ссылки на документацию с подробнейшим описанием интерполяции, где всё это уже есть. Но если вам это принципиально, то я буду не против, если вы отредактируете мой ответ и добавите свои примеры, или вообще напишете свой собственный ответ.

Comment: Пример `Console.Write($"numbers {10} {20} {30}");` не демонстрирует ничего, потому что то же результат можно получить через `Console.Write("numbers 10 20 30");`. Конечно, можно пойти по ссылке, но зачем тогда пример? Если демонстрировать интерполяцию, то переменными. Ваш ответ -
 это ваш ответ, редактировать я ничего не буду. Свой ответ не вижу смысла писать, потому что не пишу на C#.

Comment: @insolor хорошо, хорошо. Хоть по мне - разницы никакой, но раз вы настаиваете, я поверю вашему мнению и добавлю переменные в пример :)